# What type of replication do I need to push webdata to offline database for analytics?

Tags: sql-server, replication

I'm new to replication, as I've been mostly an old school ETL type person.
I have a SQL SERVER database that runs a front end web presence.  There's alot of data there.

I have been tasked to perform analytics on the web database.  However, in order to do so, I must send an extreme number of queries to the database.  This is making the db sluggish.

WHen speaking with another analyst about my problem, they stated that in the past they solved this by creating another instance on another server and set replication so I can use the Replication database and not put the pressure on the web instance.

My question is the type of replication.  When researching types of replication, I see Transactional, Merge, etc....

Is there a specific type of replication that I need for this case?  If I know what I'm hunting for, I can get the steps from there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you will be replicating from 1 db server (the web backend) to 1 reporting server and that the data will all be flowing in one direction. If what I wrote is correct I think that transactional replication will be the best fit to your needs - one of the nice things about replication is that you don´t have to include all the tables (indeed you can filter out columns or rows if required). Start by checking the tables you want to replicate have a primary key defined.